# Apache - setting proxy response headers as environment variable

Tags: apache-2.4, amazon-s3

I am proxying apache requests to s3 and
I want to rewrite the response header into a new crafted header

this is my configuration:

```
SetEnvIf x-amz-meta-link "(.*)" DYN_CSS=$0
Header set Link "</static_assets/stylesheets/application-%{DYN_CSS}e.css>; rel=preload; as=stylesheet" env=DYN_CSS
```

s3 Header is configured to be 
   x-amz-meta-link: css

I am expecting the header in the final response to be

```
 </static_assets/stylesheets/application-css.css>; rel=preloadas=stylesheet"
```

but what I get is (empty var)

```
 </static_assets/stylesheets/application-.css>;
```

---

I am guessing I should not use setEnvIf because it refers to the request header.

How can save proxied server (S3) header to an environment variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using version 2.4.10+ you can simply use
 `"expr=..."` form of the Header directive and using `%{resp:x-amz-meta-link}` to get the response header value

see more details [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

---

SetEnvIf only reads request headers, runs before response headers are available, etc.